# How to add customization to Configurable Map Viewer (CMV)?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer

Looking to learn more about CMV Viewer. For example, how would I add capability like:

map on load:

for learning how to configure CMV Viewer for my own needs, I'd like to start by learning to add "click" for "show coordinates"...

here's the example of the code I'd like to add onto my copy of CMV Viewer. Can someone teach me how to add on this type of customization?

Here's what I'd like to add:
http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=map_infowindow

Answer (score 2):

The [cmv projections widget](https://github.com/tr3vorm/cmv-projections-widget) contributed by the community is a good place to start. That widget does what you ask plus showing coordinates in multiple projections.

Comment: That is half of what I was looking for!!! That's the tool I need. Now, the other half of the answer I am hoping for: if i wanted to add that functionality, and a current cmv widget didn't exist, then the way to approach the solution would be to build a widget (otherwise, it cannot be added simply using "map on load"), is that correct?

Comment: It depends on your needs. Typically a widget (one that presents a GUI or one that is invisible) is the most flexible route. Widgets are added to the application after everything is initialized so you know the map and layers are loaded already. The best way to learn would be to look at how an existing widget is constructed and interacts with the map, layers, etc.